# Why doesn't my code append a new row to the table element?

Tags: jquery

My purpose is to append a new row to the table button element, but nothing happens when I click the button element.

I've tried checking to see if I was selecting wrong elements, but everything seems to be sentactially entacted.When I try to debug my code in the console, I couldn't find any errors to fix. Any inpuy or help would be greatly appreciated, Thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Table project</title>
  <style>
    table {
      background-color: #00FFFF;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="x" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr id="row0">
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody2">
      <tr id="row1">
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="row2">
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="row3">
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <button id="btn"> Enter Row </button>





  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#btn').click(function() {
        $("#x tbody2").append(
          "<tr>" +
          "<td>Shit</td>" +
          "<td>All over</td>" +
          "<td>Myself</td>" +
          "</tr>"
        );

      })
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just use `$("#tbody2").append(....` tbody2 is an id. You should put `#`

Comment: Thanks.. Notice how there's an extra space(column )when I add a row? How can I avoid that?

Comment: I added an answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$("#tbody2")` to select the body. Use `$("#tbody2 > tr").length` to get the count of the `<tr>`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Table project</title>
  <style>
    table {
      background-color: #00FFFF;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="x" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr id="row0">
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody2">
      <tr id="row1">
        <td scope="row">1</td>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="row2">
        <td scope="row">2</td>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="row3">
        <td scope="row">3</td>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <button id="btn"> Enter Row </button>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#btn').click(function() {

        var count = $("#tbody2 > tr").length + 1;

        $("#tbody2").append(
          "<tr id='row" + count + "'>" +
          "<td scope='row'>" + count + "</td>" +
          "<td>Shit</td>" +
          "<td>All over</td>" +
          "<td>Myself</td>" +
          "</tr>"
        );

      })
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```